# Microsoft bot framework IE11 embed issues

Tags: node.js, botframework

I am trying to embed our bot in a customer's IE11 :( We have our own embed but we are facing that Cross Origin Request is not supported. I am even willing to just embed the standard Microsoft in page embed (that chat box with a blue top border) but users need to say something with that embed first before bot starts opening sentence..

So my questions are:

- Are there any workarounds?
- Is there any working web embed that I just can reuse and plug my directline into?
- Is there a way to have this default microsoft embed startup the opening sentence automatically on loading?

Comment: Are you using BotFramework-WebChat v3 or v4? Are you including the `botchat-es5.js` file? Starting from 0.12.0, we no longer package polyfills in botchat.js. If you are on an older browser, you can use the bundle botchat-es5.js, which include polyfills for browsers which support up to ES5.

Comment: v3.. will look into that!